# X509Certificate2Signature returns ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, itext, x509certificate2

I am creating an API REST with NET 6 and EF Core.
I have a X509Certificate2 (under ITextSharp), which is created correctly as far as I can tell.
Now, after the creation of the Certificate, I need to create a X509Certificate2Signature so I can sign a PDF file with specific credentials, passing the X509Certificate2Signature to IExternalSignature. The problem relies that when I try to build the X509Certificate2Signature, it throws this:

[image]

Code is as follows (inside a try-catch block):

```
X509Certificate2 rootX509 = new X509Certificate2(
                    certificado.Cert, 
                    pass, 
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | 
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
                
                IExternalSignature external = new X509Certificate2Signature(rootX509, "RSA");
```

I am trying to replicate a behavior of an old DLL we actually use, which is in Net Framework 4.7.2.
I need to build the Certificate, so I can build from it the signature, and after that, sign a PDF file. Everything, in NET 6, using ITextSharp 5.5.
I expected to have zero problem about it, but it seems that the library has different compat/it is no longer compatible with NET 6.

EDIT: I add the stack trace, but nothing shows more details than this:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@__idArchivo_0='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='120']
SELECT TOP(1) [c].[id], [c].[cambio_estado_descargado], [c].[COMENTARIO], [c].[estado], [c].[FECHA], [c].[fecha_cambio_estado], [c].[ID_ARCHIVO_MOBILE], [c].[ID_CLIENTE], [c].[ID_TIPO_ARCHIVO], [c].[motivo_firma_no_conforme], [c].[NOMBRE], [c].[RUTA_REPO], [c].[SOLO_ADMIN], [c].[SUBIDO_ARCHIVO_AL_CLOUD], [c].[SUBIDO_CAMBIO_ESTADO_CLOUD]
FROM [CLIENTES_ARCHIVOS] AS [c]
WHERE CAST([c].[id] AS bigint) = @__idArchivo_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[@__idCliente_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='120']
SELECT TOP(1) [c].[id], [c].[ALGORITHM], [c].[APENOM], [c].[CERT], [c].[ID_EMPLEADO], [c].[ID_USUARIO], [c].[IMAGEN], [c].[ISSUER_DN], [c].[NOT_AFTER], [c].[NOT_BEFORE], [c].[PASS], [c].[SERIALNUMBER], [c].[SUBIDO_ARCHIVO_AL_CLOUD], [c].[SUBJECT_DN]
FROM [CERTIFICADOS_FIRMA] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[ID_EMPLEADO] = @__idCliente_0
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentNullException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Comment: Please share the stack trace.

Comment: Done, but there is no specification about the exception.

Comment: Your edit looks like you have an issue in some database query.

Comment: Despite it may look like that, actually the database is working just fine. In fact, the last query happens before the method where the certificate2signature issue occurs.